# servlet filter login not work right

Tags: servlets

I have a login project with servlet.

my java classes are:

LoginServlet:

```
package two;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
*/
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final String userID = "admin";
private final String password = "password";

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // get request parameters for userID and password
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

    if (userID.equals(user) && password.equals(pwd)) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", "Pankaj");
        // setting session to expiry in 30 mins
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30 * 60);
        Cookie userName = new Cookie("user", user);
        userName.setMaxAge(30 * 60);
        response.addCookie(userName);
        response.sendRedirect("loginSuccess.jsp");
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                "/login.html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
        rd.include(request, response);
    }

}

}
```

LogoutServlet:

```
package two;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LogoutServlet
*/
@WebServlet("/LogoutServlet")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
            System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    //invalidate the session if exists
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("User="+session.getAttribute("user"));
    if(session != null){
        session.invalidate();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("login.html");
}

}
```

AuthenticationFilter:

```
package two;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebFilter("/AuthenticationFilter")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

private ServletContext context;

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    this.context.log("Requested Resource::" + uri);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session == null
            && !(uri.endsWith("html") || uri.endsWith("LoginServlet"))) {
        this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
        res.sendRedirect("login.html");
    } else {
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

public void destroy() {
    // close any resources here
}

}
```

RequestLoggingFilter:

```
package two;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class RequestLoggingFilter
 */
@WebFilter("/RequestLoggingFilter")
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements Filter {

private ServletContext context;

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
    this.context.log("RequestLoggingFilter initialized");
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    Enumeration<String> params = req.getParameterNames();
    while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = params.nextElement();
        String value = request.getParameter(name);
        this.context.log(req.getRemoteAddr() + "::Request Params::{" + name
                + "=" + value + "}");
    }

    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            this.context.log(req.getRemoteAddr() + "::Cookie::{"
                    + cookie.getName() + "," + cookie.getValue() + "}");
        }
    }
    // pass the request along the filter chain
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {
    // we can close resources here
}

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>ServletPractice</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
the rendered HTML output.
If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
that submits the corresponding form.
If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
will be added as url parameters.
Default is 'true'</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
influence the HTML code.
Default is 'true'</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
Default is 'false'
</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
<filter-name>RequestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>two.RequestLoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
<filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>two.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>RequestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>two/LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/two/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

loginSuccess.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Login Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    //allow access only if session exists
    String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
    String userName = null;
    String sessionID = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("user"))
                userName = cookie.getValue();
            if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
                sessionID = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
%>
<h3>
    Hi
    <%=userName%>, Login successful. Your Session ID=<%=sessionID%></h3>
<br> User=<%=user%>
<br>
<a href="CheckoutPage.jsp">Checkout Page</a>
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

RequestLoggingFilter:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Login Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    //allow access only if session exists
    String user = (String) session.getAttribute("user");
    String userName = null;
    String sessionID = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            if (cookie.getName().equals("user"))
                userName = cookie.getValue();
            if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID"))
                sessionID = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
%>
<h3>
    Hi
    <%=userName%>, Login successful. Your Session ID=<%=sessionID%></h3>
<br> User=<%=user%>
<br>
<a href="CheckoutPage.jsp">Checkout Page</a>
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when I submit in login page , it give 404 error:
 The requested resource (/ServletPractice/two/LoginServlet) is not available.

and my browser addressBar change to : localhost:9090/ServletPractice/two/LoginServlet

please help me. thankes

Answer (score 0):

This initial problem looks like it's with the HTML Login form.  I'm assuming, based on the address bar that you receive, you are using `localhost:9090/ServletPractice/two/login.html` as the login page.

The form `<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">...</form>` will post to "LoginServlet" at the same level as the HTML page containing the form, but given that you've mapped the login servlet to "/LoginServlet" rather than "/two/LoginServlet" it's not found at the location.

I would therefore try changing the form to be:

```
<form action="/ServletPractice/LoginServlet" method="post">...</form>
```

or maybe

```
<form action="/LoginServlet" method="post">...</form>
```